# Issue when moving Vim9script plugin's functions to autoload

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings, plugin-system, vim9script

I've read `:help write-plugin` to understand a bit more about how to write a plugin in Vim9script, but there aspects of that that puzzle me.

Here's a very simplified, working version of the example constructed at the aforementioned help page (the following file is in `~/.vim/plugin/.`):

```
vim9script noclear

if exists("g:loaded_messingaround")
  finish
endif
g:loaded_messingaround = 1
var save_cpo = &cpo
set cpo&vim

if !hasmapto('<Plug>MessingAround;')
  map <unique> <Leader>a  <Plug>MessingAround;
endif
noremap <unique> <script> <Plug>MessingAround; :echo <SID>Say(expand("<cword>"))<CR>

def Say(str: string): string
  return str
enddef

&cpo = save_cpo
```

Leaving aside the boilerplate, the code above essentially maps <kbd>Leader</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to the ex command `:echo …`, which prints to screen whatever `Say` returns, which is the same as it gets as argument.

This piece of code works as expected; or, at least, as I expect: if I hit <kbd>Leader</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> on a word, that word is `echo`ed back.

---

But what if I want to have `Say` defined in `autoload`?

In an attempt to do so, I changed the file above to look like this:

```
vim9script noclear

import autoload 'messingaround.vim' as xyz

if exists("g:loaded_messingaround")
  finish
endif
g:loaded_messingaround = 1
var save_cpo = &cpo
set cpo&vim

if !hasmapto('<Plug>MessingAround;')
  map <unique> <Leader>a  <Plug>MessingAround;
endif
noremap <unique> <script> <Plug>MessingAround; :echo <ScriptCmd>xyz.Say(expand("<cword>"))<CR>

&cpo = save_cpo
```

Essentially, I added the `import` line and removed the definition of `Say`, which I've moved into a `~/.vim/autoload/messingaround.vim` and modified by adding the `export` keyword:

```
vim9script noclear

export def Say(str: string): string
  return str
enddef
```

At this point, if I open a new Vim session, put my cursor on a word, and hit <kbd>Leader</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, what I get is that the command line is populated with `:echo`  (including the trailing space), which looks a bit like Vim hasn't even read the `<ScriptCmd>xyz.Say(expand("<cword>"))<CR>` part of the `noremap`ping.

Comment: The mailing list or bug-tracker on GitHub may be a reasonable second place to ask; I see lots of vim9 stuff crop up there

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, you mean [vim's GitHub](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+vim9)?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being clearer!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, no, you were clear. It's just that I thought I might be not aware of another Vim9 specific repository (I see there's one, but it's read-only). Anyway, [posted](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/10186).

Comment: Great, if you get answer(s) please post them here (with attribution, of course)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, a thorough discussion has been going on [there](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/10186). However, 1. I've never got an extremely clear understanding, and 2. some time has passed since last time I looked it; so at the moment I don't feel confident to convert that info in an answer. I'll probably do it at some point in the future.